# How would I print just one element out of this multidimensional array? (I can't tell how this array is laid out)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that I cannot mentally assess at the moment, and would like to know how I might print out just ONE element from the array, e.g. print $cities["City"[0][0][0]... (I don't know exactly how many [] there should be to get at just one element...

```
<?php 




$cities = array( array("City"=>"New York", "State"=> "NY", "Population"=>8175133),
               array("City"=>"Los Angeles", "State"=> "CA" , "Population"=>3792621),
               array("City"=>"Chicago", "State"=> "IL" , "Population"=>2695598),
               array("City"=>"Houston", "State"=> "TX" , "Population"=>2100263),
               array("City"=>"Philadelphia", "State"=> "PA" , "Population"=>1526006),
               array("City"=>"Phoenix", "State"=> "AZ" , "Population"=>1445632),
               array("City"=>"San Antonio", "State"=> "TX" , "Population"=>1327407),
               array("City"=>"San Diego", "State"=> "CA" , "Population"=>1307402),
               array("City"=>"Dallas", "State"=> "TX" , "Population"=>1197816),
           array("City"=>"San Jose","State" => "CA", "Population"=>945942)  
             ); 


//what I want to do (very simple)
print $cities["City"][0][0] //....????


/*
?>

<?php if (count($cities) > 0): ?>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><?php echo implode('</th><th>', array_keys(current($cities))); ?></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php foreach ($cities as $row): array_map('htmlentities', $row); ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo implode('</td><td>', $row); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>



*/
```

I just want to be able to print out an element of this array.

Comment: `echo $cities[0]['City']` should be `'New York'`, `echo $cities[0]['State']` should be `'NY'`, and so on.

Comment: ^ This was helpful and did the trick, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array when you print it out looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [City] => New York
            [State] => NY
            [Population] => 8175133
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [City] => Los Angeles
            [State] => CA
            [Population] => 3792621
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [City] => Chicago
            [State] => IL
            [Population] => 2695598
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [City] => Houston
            [State] => TX
            [Population] => 2100263
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [City] => Philadelphia
            [State] => PA
            [Population] => 1526006
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [City] => Phoenix
            [State] => AZ
            [Population] => 1445632
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [City] => San Antonio
            [State] => TX
            [Population] => 1327407
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [City] => San Diego
            [State] => CA
            [Population] => 1307402
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [City] => Dallas
            [State] => TX
            [Population] => 1197816
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [City] => San Jose
            [State] => CA
            [Population] => 945942
        )
```

This means you have an array with 10 elements in it.

Each element contains it's own array that consist of three elements for you city, state, and population.

To access the 5 element's city value you would do this:

```
echo $cities[4]['City']; //<---Philadelphia
```

Arrays start counting(indexing) at 0.  So the 5th element is actually indexed at #4.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

`echo $x[0]['City'];` would print out "New York"

It is $city[*index*][*key*]